# "App init setup failed: a project already exists" MongoDB Realm App

Tags: mongodb, realm, command-line-interface, mongodb-realm

I have an error message that I do know know who to fix regarding Mongodb Realm CLI.
https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/cli/realm-cli-apps-create/

When I write the following command in Terminal:

`realm-cli apps init -n "test"`

I get the error message "app init setup failed: a project already exists"

I have already had a project name "test" but I have deleted it (Simply deleting the folder which might have been the mistake) but I still get the error message. The error occurs always, no matter the name or path/folder at the moment.

if `realm-cli push` is used it seems to use the old "test" application since the name is filled out when going through the [options]
https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/cli/realm-cli-push/

If I push the application it will deploy the test application and if deleted through either CLI or GUI it returns to the first problem mention at the start.

Where to go from here? Is the application somehow stored as a draft or something making it impossible for me to create another before its discarded or am I missing something?